# why products url is repeating in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm using `Magento 1.7.0`. I want to show latest ordered products on homepage sidebar. Almost everything is ready and working properly except its URL.

I don't know why products URL is repeating again and again. Products' images, it's name and price is showing correct only it's URL gets repeated for each product.

Each product have the same first product URL.

Here is the code

```
        <style>
        .productList { float:left; width:720px; }
        .productList .product { background:#fff; border:1px solid #eedfa6;  padding:3px;   float:left; text-align:center; width: 182px; margin-bottom: 7px; height: 200px; }
        .productList .product .cl { padding:0 0 0 0px; text-align:center;}
        .productList .product .prodDetails {font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px; color: #2a2a28;text-align:center; padding:0 0 0 0px;  }
        .productList .product .prodDetails a{color: #d77932;}
        .productList .product .prodDetails a:hover{color: #3d4d68 ;}
        .productList .product .addCompare { text-align:center;  clear:both; }
        .productList .product .addWishlist {clear:both; text-align:center; }

        }
        </style>
        <?php
        $result = $this->getBestsellerProduct();
        $itemPerRow = ($this->getItemsPerRow()) ? $this->getItemsPerRow() : 2 ;
        //getting product model
        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $products_price = Mage::getStoreConfig('bestseller/general/products_price');  
        $review = Mage::getStoreConfig('bestseller/general/review');  
        ?>
        <div style="width:200px;float:right;">
        <div class="sectionHead" style=""><h2><?php echo $this->getHeader(); ?></h2><div style="height: 25px;border-bottom: 2px solid #eedfa6 /*#DBDBDB;*/"    class="hrline"></div></div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="productList" style="width:100px;">

            <?php  $i=0;
            for($cnt = 0; $cnt<5; $cnt++){
            $_product = $model->load($result[$cnt]); //getting product object for particular product id

            ?>
            <tr>
            <td class="product">
            <div class="prodimage">
            <!-- code added by Saurabh-->
            <?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>
            <?php if ($_product->getExt_image_url()!=''){$srcImage=$_product->getExt_image_url();} else{$srcImage=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image');} ?>
            <!--saurabh code ended here-->
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $srcImage; ?>" width="150" height="145" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
            <div class="prodDetails" align="center" style="width:175px;" >

                                                        <?php $_product_name=  $_product->getName(); ?>
                    <?php $_short_product_name = substr($_product_name, 0, 40);  ?>
                                                        <?php  $_dot_product_name=$_short_product_name.'...' ; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $_dot_product_name ;?></a>

            <?php  if($review == 1) 
            {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
            echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); 
            }
            if($products_price == 1) 
            {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
            echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); 
            } 
            ?>                
            </div>
            <?php $addtocartval = $this->getAddToCart();
            if($addtocartval == 1){
            if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

            <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
            <?php endif; }?>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">
            <?php $wishlists = $this->getActive();
            if($wishlists == 1){
            if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="addWishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
            <?php endif; }?>
            </div>  
            <div class="cl">
            <?php $addtocompare = $this->getAddToCompare();
            if($addtocompare==1){
            if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
            &nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl; ?>" class="addCompare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a>
            <?php endif; }?>
            </div>
            </td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ,check  `$result[$cnt]` is `same for every time`??

```
     for($cnt = 0; $cnt<5; $cnt++){
    // change code here
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($result[$cnt]);
     $my_product_url = $product->getProductUrl();
    //or
    $my_product_url=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
      ->getAttributeRawValue($result[$cnt], 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
   //or
    $my_product_url=Mage::getUrl()''.$_product->getData('url_key').'.html';
```

Comment: issue  $model  object. ,this object have  take product object